# SQL not connecting to Linked Oracle Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

We have SQL Server 2014, with the latest CU, running with Oracle client version 11.2.0.1.0 installed.

We have about 25 linked Oracle servers connected on it. The servers are running of mix of Oracle 10,11,12 and 19, and can connect to all without issues.

We're trying to connect this SQL server to 2 new Oracle servers (A Production, and BCV copy), which are both running 19.

**While attempting to connect to the Prod server, we get the `ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol` error.**

[image]
**While attempting to connect to the BCV server, The username/password gets rejected.**

- It will connect fine to either server directly in Oracle SQL developer, therefore we're certain about the credentials and TNS entries
- Can TNSPing both Oracle servers on the SQL server box just fine
- I don't see how this can be a compatibility issue, as we've linked four Oracle 19 servers
- The `PASSWORD_VERSION` attributes for the Oracle login is set to `11G 12C`
- We've added the 2 attributes in the SQLnet.ora file, but no luck:

  `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=11`

  `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=11`

Anything we're missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntdbi/oracle-database-software-requirements.html#GUID-CEF225E9-9600-4E01-AC6F-402B562385F8), Oracle Database 19c requires a minimum client version of 11.2.0.4, so you will need to upgrade your client.

You will also need to reset the passwords for all users with this client *after* setting the `PASSWORD_VERSION` parameter to ensure that password hashes with the compatible `11G` algorithms are generated.

Comment: Thanks! I successfully patched the client and can connect without issues. Didn't have to change passwords though.